# django template language if and else statement, if works but else doesn't show anything

Tags: python, django

here's what I'm trying to do. User can insert url, and if that url is a youtube link I want to display the video thumbnail.(I'm using django-embeded-video) if the url isn't youtube link, I want some ohter image(post.image) to show up. So I'm using else,if statement for this.

```
 {% if post.url %}
  {% video post.url as my_video %}
  {% if my_video %}
        <img src="{{ my_video.thumbnail }}" class="img-rounded" alt="☺" height="75" width="75"/>
  {% else %}
<img src="{{post.image}}"  class="img-rounded" alt="☺" height="75" width="75"/>
  {% endif %}
{% endvideo %}
{% endif %}
```

with above code, video thumbnail shows up when url is youtube link. but when url isn't youtube link nothing shows up.

If I do this;

```
  {% if post.url %}
<img src="{{post.image}}"  class="img-rounded" alt="☺ EBAGU" height="75" width="75"/>
```

the image shows up...

not sure why "else" isn't working

```
Edit: img src={{post.image}} works 
img src={{my_video.thumbnail}} works
I want if img src={{my_video.thumbnail}} isn't there I want {{post.image}} to appear
```

Comment: Could you show the `video` template tag definition? Thanks.

Comment: @alecxe thanks for the response, http://django-embed-video.readthedocs.org/en/v1.1.0/examples.html#template-examples

Comment: Can you also display the value of `my_video` in both the cases because you are checking for `{% if my_video %}`. Are you sure you want to display image by checking this condition or as an else block of `post.url` check.

Comment: @AKS I'm sorry I'm little bit confused about what you are asking, what do you mean by both?I'm checking if my_video is there, if it's there I want to display x, else display y. how should I check?

Comment: @AKS now I see what you mean by both cases, I tried {% else my_video %} I get No exception message supplied

Comment: By both cases I mean what is the value of `my_video` when you expect else block to be displayed?

Comment: @AKS my_video should be none for else statement...hmm this gives me something to think about. hmm...thanks

Comment: @mikebraa yet again, we can always talk about what _should be_ but if you read both of my comments above it is more about what is the value you have for `my_video` with current implementation. Along with that could you also add some examples of `post.url`.

Comment: @AKS my_video is just an youtube video, I have form url, and users can insert urls there. youtube link gets youbube video and that video is my_video.  post.url is just an url....not sure why you need them...

Comment: have you tried testing `{% if my_video.thumbnail %}` instead?

Comment: @xthestreams No the point is to display post.image....the video thumbnail gets displayed fine

Answer (score 1):

You can Try this:

```
 {% if post.url %}
   {% video post.url as my_video %}
   {% if my_video %}
       <img src="{{ my_video.thumbnail }}"/>
   {% else %}
       <img src="{{ MEDIA_URL }}{{ post.image }}"/>
       <!-- or <img src="{% static 'Path/To?You/static/image.png' %}"/> if You not upload image everytime-->
   {% endif %}
 {% endif %}
```

At first You need upload post.image

Comment: this doesn't work...well I think it doesn't work with the above code is because the image isn't video/mp4 and I don't think I need <video> tags between thumbnail image

Comment: Do You want to run video or image?

Comment: that's exactly what I did except I don't need {{media_url}}, as mentioned above <img src="{{post.image}}"  class="img-rounded" alt="☺ " height="75" width="75"/> gets displayed fine